# How I can read only a interval of a file content in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, file, dart

i'm manipulating a file to store information in the app in flutter. For example purposes consider a file .txt with the following items as String:

```
[ value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4, ... value 500, ]
```

my app should be very quick in this reading, I'm looking for a way to read only a range of this file, for example from item 0 to item 20. Would you have a way to do this **without** throwing the entire value of the file into a var? I'd like to stop reading as soon as I've reached the limit.
currently i do that way with *path provider*:

```
Future<String> load() async {
    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final File file = File('${directory.path}/names.txt');

    return await file.readAsString();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read only portions of a file, you need [*random access*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access), and thus you need to use [`File.open`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/open.html)/[`File.openSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/File/openSync.html) to obtain a [`RandomAccessFile`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/RandomAccessFile-class.html):

```dart
var file = File('path/to/file');
var randomAccessFile = file.openSync();
try {
  var bytes = randomAccessFile.readSync(20); // Read the first 20 bytes.
  ...
} finally {
  randomAccessFile.closeSync();
}
```

Alternatively you could use [`File.openRead`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/openRead.html) to create a `Stream` that reads a portion of the specified file.